# Assigning values to variables from controls where 'empty', there must be a better way!

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, null

I have a winform app for in house use where the below is very common.

```
            Int32? afhAgreement = null;
            if (!lkuReveiewAFHAgreement.Text.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                afhAgreement = (Int32)lkuReveiewAFHAgreement.EditValue;
            }
            DateTime? afhAgreementDate = null;
            if (datAFHAgreementCompleted.Text != String.Empty)
            {
                afhAgreementDate = (DateTime?)datAFHAgreementCompleted.EditValue;
            }
            Int32? crisisPlan = null;
            if (!lkuReview6MonthCrisisPlan.Text.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                crisisPlan = (Int32)lkuReview6MonthCrisisPlan.EditValue;
            }
            DateTime? crisisPlanDate = null;
            if (dat6MonthCrisisPlanReviewed.Text != String.Empty)
            {
                crisisPlanDate = (DateTime?)dat6MonthCrisisPlanReviewed.EditValue;
            }
            Int32? riskAgreement = null;
            if (!lkuReviewRiskAssessment.Text.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                riskAgreement = (Int32)lkuReviewRiskAssessment.EditValue;
            }
            DateTime? riskAgreementDate = null;
            if (!datRiskAssessmentReviewed.Text.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                riskAgreementDate = (DateTime?)datRiskAssessmentReviewed.EditValue;
            }
```

Seeing as all of those variables can be `NULL` it seems like this is a ridiculous way to do this.  Isn't there a `Convert this object and Default to NULL`?

By the way, `EditValue` is an object though I believe I have the same issue even if I use the `Text` property of the control.

So, is there a better way?  Is this something I could simplify with `Extension Methods`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add some reusable functions... for example:

```
static T? GetValue<T>(YourControlType control) where T : struct
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text)) return null;
    return (T)control.EditValue;
}
```

And then (for example):

```
DateTime? crisisPlanDate = GetValue<DateTime>(dat6MonthCrisisPlanReviewed);
```

(where `YourControlType` is whatever control you are using with a `string .Text` and `object .EditValue`)

Comment: So I would create a function similar to this for EACH control type, correct?  DateTime, LookUp, etc...

Comment: If you have a single control type, then that wouldn't be necessary - but it isn't clear from the question.

Comment: Sorry about that!  Yes, I have multiple control types.  In the question `lku` would refer to a LookUp Drop Down Box and `dat` refers to a DateEdit Box.  There are others too I was just trying to keep the question simplistic enough that people would answer.

Answer (score 1):

something like this..

```
afhAgreement = (!lkuReveiewAFHAgreement.Text.Equals(string.Empty)) ? (Int32)lkuReveiewAFHAgreement.EditValue : null;

riskAgreement = (!lkuReviewRiskAssessment.Text.Equals(string.Empty))  ? (Int32)lkuReviewRiskAssessment.EditValue : null;
```